# Is it possible to add this kind of default value to Caesar cypher python?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, signature

Here is a basic function call I would like to do,
As you can see below in the signature, I would like to have the default value in s be the length of the string passed in for convenience. Is it possible to do this in python? Or some version of this?

```
def encrypt(text, s=len(text)):
        result = ""
    
        # transverse the plain text
        for i in range(len(text)):
            char = text[i]
            # Encrypt uppercase characters in plain text
    
            if (char.isupper()):
                result += chr((ord(char) + s - 65) % 26 + 65)
            # Encrypt lowercase characters in plain text
            else:
                result += chr((ord(char) + s - 97) % 26 + 97)
        return result
```

Comment: Default values are evaluated at the time the function was defined - `text` had no specific value at that time, so `len(text)` isn't meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the right way:

```
def encrypt(text, s=None):
    if s is None:
        s = len(text)
```

Comment: `s is None` instead, as 0 appears to be a valid input for this function.

Comment: If you want.  Asking to encrypt 0 characters of a string is likely to explode anyway.

Comment: s appears to be the offset for a caesar, so 0 is valid.